# ¿Como reemplazar mysqli_result() en PHP7?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy atorado necesito actualizar este código pues al parecer varias cosas ya no funcionan en `PHP7` y no se cual es el equivalente a la clase `mysqli_result` el error que me muestra es el siguiente:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()

Este es el código:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
//DBC();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM outbox WHERE status = 'U' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if( $num > 0 ){
        $id_sms = mysqli_result($result,0,"id_sms");
        $cels = mysqli_result($result,0,"cels");
        $message = mysqli_result($result,0,"message");

        echo "<cels>".$cels."</cels>
            <message>".$message."</message>
            <id_sms>".$id_sms."</id_sms>";

        $sql = "UPDATE outbox SET status = 'B' WHERE id_sms = 
   '".$id_sms."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    }
    else{
        echo "EMPTY";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
```

Comment: ¿obtienes algún error?, de ser así recomiendo agregarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que realmente no existe una función `mysqli_result` en la extensión `MySQLi` (*si la habia en [`MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-result.php), notese que no tiene `i`*)

### Opción 1 (*refactorización*):

Dado que aparentemente esta migrando tu código de la extensión [`MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysql.php) a [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php), te recomiendo usar [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
//DBC();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM outbox WHERE status = 'U' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if( $num > 0 ){
  // AQUI obtenemos los datos 
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  echo "<cels>".$row['cels']."</cels>
      <message>".$row['message']."</message>
      <id_sms>".$row['id_sms']."</id_sms>";

  $sql = "UPDATE outbox SET status = 'B' WHERE id_sms = '".$row['id_sms']."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
}
else{
  echo "EMPTY";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

---

### Opción 2 (*sin refactorización*):

Puede crear la función `mysqli_result` y que imite el funcionamiento de la anterior

#### Ejemplo:

```
function mysqli_result($res,$row=0,$col=0){ 
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($res); 
    if ($numrows && $row <= ($numrows-1) && $row >=0){
        mysqli_data_seek($res,$row);
        $resrow = (is_numeric($col)) ? mysqli_fetch_row($res) : mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        if (isset($resrow[$col])){
            return $resrow[$col];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Créditos:

- [Respuesta original en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20961496/3791844)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ha funcionado!