# equivalente Mysqli de mysql_result()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

me he topado con otro bache en el camino de la migracion a mysqli (esto de ser novato es un poco fustrante), como pongo en el titulo busco un equivalente en mysqli para la funcion mysql_result() del tipo $mysqli->result() si existiese.

```
<?php
$codproveedor=$_GET["codproveedor"];
$consulta="SELECT * FROM proves WHERE codproveedor='$codproveedor' 
AND borrado=0";
$rs_tabla = $con->query($consulta);
if ($rs_tabla->num_rows>0) {
    ?>
    <script languaje="javascript">
    pon_prefijo("<?php echo mysql_result($rs_tabla,0,nombre) ?>");
    </script>
    <?php 
} else { ?>
```

Comment: he añadido el codigo que necesito cambiar entre otros trozos de codigo pero aqui se ve bastante bien lo que quiero modificar ¿quizas funcionaria con un $rs_tabla[0, nombre]? o algo parecido.

Comment: Revisa la documentación oficial de `php` https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php . Si te apasiona la programación, no te rindas, a todos se nos dificulta en mayor o menor grado ciertas cosas... **_aún quienes son experimentados se enfrentan a retos que les sacan canas._**

Comment: @DjCrazy entonces yo acabare con menos de 30 años y el pelo blanco jajajaja, el manual ya lo revise pero no entiendo muy bien como aplicar la correcion

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como reemplazar mysqli\_result() en PHP7?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/296580/como-reemplazar-mysqli-result-en-php7)

Comment: gracias @DjCrazy creo que con ese enlace que me enviaste he encontrado solucion debido a que con la refactorizacion que explica en el puedo encontrar los equivalentes orientandolo a objetos :) en cuanto tenga el script modificado y funcione envio la solucion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he conseguido una solución para este bache, pongo el archivo original y el archivo modificado del que quizás fue el que mas me costo resolver.

validar.php "original mysql"

```
<?php
require_once("conectar.php");
$user=$_POST["user"];
$pass=$_POST["pass"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$user' and pass=SHA128('$pass')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count>0){
session_name('VALIDADO');
session_start();
session_cache_limiter('nocache,private');
$cons="SELECT * FROM users WHERE usuario='$user'";
$rs_cons=mysql_query($cons,$conexion);
$nombre=mysql_result($rs_cons,0,"nombre");
$pass=mysql_result($rs_cons,0,"pass");
$_SESSION["user"]=mysql_result($rs_cons,0,"usuario");
$_SESSION["id"]=mysql_result($rs_cons,0,"id");
$_SESSION["nombre"]=$nombre;
$_SESSION["pass"]=$pass;
$nivel=mysql_result($rs_cons,0,"nivel");
$_SESSION["nivel"]=$nivel;
$_SESSION['hora']=time();
header("location:index.php");
}
else {
header("location:login.php?errordatos=si");
}
?>
```

y aqui el archivo modificado

validar.php Mysqli

```
<?php
include 'conectar.php';
session_cache_limiter('nocache,private');
$user= htmlspecialchars($_POST['user']);
$pass= htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$user' and pass= SHA128('$pass')";
$result = $con->query($sql) or die($con->error);
$count = $result->num_rows;
if($count>0){
$cons="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user='$user'";
$rscons=$con->query($cons) or die($con->error);
$num = $rscons->num_rows;
$row = $rscons->fetch_array();
if($num>0){        
$nombre = $row['nombre'];
$pass= $row['pass'];
$_SESSION['user']= $row['usuario'];
$_SESSION['id']= $row['id'];
$_SESSION['nombre']=$nombre;
$_SESSION['pass']=$pass;
$nivel= $row['nivel'];
$_SESSION['nivel']=$nivel;
$_SESSION['hora']=time();
header("location:index.php");
}else{
    echo "EMPTY";
}
}else {
header("location:login.php?errordatos=si");
}
?>
```

espero les sirva